# Failed to ssh to school server from home

Tags: ssh

I have always been using ssh in Ubuntu terminal to my school server to do assignment, but somehow this doesn't work anymore and I am sure it is not caused by the school server since I am able to ssh to it at other places.
This is the command line that I use `ssh -v blah@linux.student.cs.ublah.ca`
the -v tag gives the following output

```
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu4, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca [129.97.167.126] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/cs136/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cs136/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cs136/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/cs136/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-
4ubuntu6local2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6local2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'linux.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/cs136/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Connection closed by 129.97.167.126
```

Anyone can tell what's wrong??

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/32725/ssh-pubkey-authentication-works-only-if-another-session-is-already-open

Answer (score 0):

Check permission on your `~/.ssh` dir

See http://boardreader.com/thread/SSH_Roaming_not_allowed_by_server_b1ltXnjn.html

Comment: Ah. I see the change in answer. I was referring to previously edited answer. :)

Comment: Mine is `drwxr-x---` and it's working. Take care of `StrictModes yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Files inside  are `-rw-------`

Comment: so u mean I need to chmod on the ssh dir?

Comment: Yes, or put some beer on, up to you.